# UICollectionView Cells resize incorrectly on reloadData()

Tags: ios, swift

My view has a table view with a collection view on each row. The collection cells have a text field (well a subclass thereof), a label and a text view which are all full size and all but one are hidden depending on cell position.

When one of the text fields is edited the delegate (CollectionView) passes the new value back to the view controller to alter the array then the appropriate cells are reloaded as there is computed data in them.

The problem is the second time one of the text fields is edited two cells swap widths, it seems to swap back if you edit the text field two more times, but the border stays in the wrong position.

**Table after initial load:**

[image]

**Table after changing quantity twice**

[image]

**text field and view delegate methods**

```
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let currencyField = textField as! CurrencyField
        let indexPath = indexPathForCellWithSubview(cellSubview: textField)!
        (dataSource as! DetailViewController).changeData(tableRow: tag, collectionItem: indexPath.row, newData: currencyField.decimal)
        let indexPaths: [IndexPath] = [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0),IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0),IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0),IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)]

        collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let indexPath = indexPathForCellWithSubview(cellSubview: textView)!
        let indexPaths: [IndexPath] = [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0),IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0),IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0),IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)]
        let dec = textView.text!.decimalFromString()
        if(dec != 0){
            (dataSource as! DetailViewController).changeData(tableRow: tag, collectionItem: indexPath.row, newData: dec)
            reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
        } else {
            (dataSource as! DetailViewController).changeData(tableRow: tag, collectionItem: indexPath.row, newData: textView.text!)
        }
        collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
```

**Array**

```
var dummyData: [[Any]] = [
    ["Fencing garden",Decimal(1),Decimal(8500.00)],
    ["Ditching",Decimal(1),Decimal(1950.00)],
    ["Fred",Decimal(1),Decimal(1950.00)]]
```

**Cell widths**

```
let table4Cells: [Int] = [310,65,100,105]
let table6Cells: [Int] = [250,40,80,50,80,80]
```

**Data setting and getting**

```
func changeData(tableRow: Int, collectionItem: Int, newData: Any){

    var qty: Decimal = dummyData[tableRow][1] as! Decimal
    var cost: Decimal = dummyData[tableRow][2] as! Decimal
    var total: Decimal

    switch(collectionItem){
    case 1:
        qty = newData as! Decimal
    case 2:
        cost = newData as! Decimal
    case 3:
        total = newData as! Decimal
        cost = total / qty
    case 5:
        total = newData as! Decimal
        cost = (total / qty) / (1 + vatPC)
    default: dummyData[tableRow][collectionItem] = newData
    }
    dummyData[tableRow][1] = qty
    dummyData[tableRow][2] = cost
}

func collectionViewCellText(tag: Int, row: Int) -> String {
    var text: String = ""
    if(tag == 666){
        if(!vatRegistered && row == 3){
            return tableHeaderText[5]
        } else {
            return tableHeaderText[row]
        }
    } else {
        let qty: Decimal = dummyData[tag][1] as! Decimal
        let cost: Decimal = dummyData[tag][2] as! Decimal
        switch(row){
        case 3:
            if(vatRegistered){
                text = String(describing: vatPC * 100)
            } else {
                text = String(describing: qty * cost)
            }
        case 4:
            text = String(describing: cost * vatPC)
        case 5:
            text = String(describing: qty * (cost * (1 + vatPC)))
        default:
            text = String(describing: dummyData[tag][row])
        }
    }
    return text
}
```

**size for cell at indexpath**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if(vatRegistered){
            return CGSize(width: self.table6Cells[indexPath.row], height:self.collectionCellHeight)
        }
        return CGSize(width: self.table4Cells[indexPath.row], height:self.collectionCellHeight)
    }
```

**cell for row at index path**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell",
                                                      for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! InvoiceCollectionViewCell
        cell.textView.delegate = self
        if(collectionView is RJCollectionView){
            cell.currencyField.delegate = collectionView as! RJCollectionView
            cell.textView.delegate = collectionView as! RJCollectionView
        }
        if(collectionView.tag == 666){
            if(indexPath.row == 0){
                cell.addBorder(side: .left, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
                cell.addBorder(side: .right, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
                cell.addBorder(side: .top, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
                cell.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
            } else {
                cell.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                cell.textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                cell.addBorder(side: .right, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
                cell.addBorder(side: .top, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
                cell.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
            }
        } else {
            if(indexPath.row == 0){
                cell.addBorder(side: .left, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
                cell.addBorder(side: .right, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
                cell.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
            } else {
                cell.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                cell.textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                cell.addBorder(side: .right, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
                cell.addBorder(side: .bottom, thickness: 0.5, color: UIColor.black)
            }
            if(vatRegistered){
                switch(indexPath.row){
                case 2,5: cell.textType(i: "CurrencyView")
                case 3:
                    cell.textType(i: "TextView")
                    cell.textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                case 4:
                    cell.currencyField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                    cell.textType(i: "CurrencyView")
                default: cell.textType(i: "TextView")
                }

            } else {
                switch(indexPath.row){
                case 2,3: cell.textType(i: "CurrencyView")
                default: cell.textType(i: "TextView")
                }
            }
        }

        if(collectionView.tag == 0){
            print(cell.currencyField.bounds.width)
        }

        cell.text = collectionViewCellText(tag: collectionView.tag, row: indexPath.row)

        return cell
    }
```

NB: collectionview.tag is the row on the table the collection view is in. 666 is the header row. vatRegistered is a bool that when true sets width of collection view to 6 rather than 4 cells

Comment: Usually when I try to do something this complex, I take a look around to see if someone else has done it better than I could ;). Might be worth looking at https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView

Comment: I wonder whether this is an appropriate use of collection view.

Comment: thanks for the tip brandon, I'll look into that before my next project, for what it's worth I fixed the bug with my method, there seems to be a bug with the uicollectionviecell contentView sizing in iOS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update:

I stripped out my whole project into a secondary project and put the collectionview directly into the main view, but still had the issue

It seems the issue was being caused by the contentView not resizing to the size of the cell, which appears to be a bug with iOS so when the cells were pushed and popped onto the stack on reload they switched order, but for whatever reason setting the cell size didn't reset the size of the contentView.

adding:

```
    cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds;
    cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

to the sizeforitem flow layout method fixed the weird offsets.

the border in the wrong place is down to the uiview extension i use to add the borders, it just adds a view of a set width to whichever edge it's asked to, this has to be removed when reusing the cells

Comment: what an astonishing bug!  it's still present, late 2019  :/

Comment: from the storyboard choose the CollectionView - Size Inspector - by default "Estimate Size" was automatic. Changed it to "NO" has been solved my issue.

Comment: Still a bug in July 2020 - thank you for sharing your issue and learnings!  For me, as my collection view cell height is fixed - I solved via IB and changing Collection View 'Cell Size' and Estimated size > Custom to the right height.

Comment: Still a bug in Aug 2022

Comment: Still a bug in Jul 2023